# Count details over a specific detail set of data

Tags: excel

I have a table like this

```
local   machine1    machine2    machine3
------  ---------   ---------   ---------
local1  test1-a     
local1  test2-a     test2-b     test2-c
local1  test3-a     test3-b 
local2  test4-a     test4-b 
local2  test5-a     
local2  test6-a     
local2  test7-a     
local3  test8-a     test8-b     test8-c
local3  test9-a     test9-b
```

I have a formula like this to count the number of certain type of local

```
=COUNTIF($a$3:$a$20;"local1") - result: 3
=COUNTIF($a$3:$a$20;"local2") - result: 4
=COUNTIF($a$3:$a$20;"local3") - result: 2
```

So far so good.

Now, the objective is to get the count of how many machines are there for each local, and that I really can't get to do.
Ideas?

EDIT: modified data to be more easily read

The result for the count should be:

Local1: 6 
local2: 5 
local3: 5

Comment: Please clarify your dataset. Which machine is related to which local? For example why are the machines local2-a, local2-b and local2-c in one row with local1 in the second data row? In other words: What exactly means "count of how many machines are there for each local". Give examples for the count results please.

Comment: @Axel, sorry ,the data was corrected. The cout resoult should be : Local1 - 6; local2 - 5; local3 - 5

Comment: Basically, what I want is to count the number of machines that exist for each local, being this local given by the data set given by the previous formula, example: =COUNTIF($a$3:$a$20;"local1"). For the example in display, the data is organized, but it's never the case ...all the local are mixed in a table with about 5k records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope, I have understand it right:

[image]

Formulas in

`G2` and 3 cells downwards:

```
=COUNTIF($A:$A,F2)
```

`G7`and 3 cells downwards:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A$20=F7)*($B$1:$D$20<>""))
```

It uses the power of the swiss army knife `SUMPRODUCT`. `($A$1:$A$20=F7)` is true if the local matches in `A`. `($B$1:$D$20<>"")` is true if the machine cell is not empty. If both are true, then `TRUE * TRUE` = `1`, else `FALSE * TRUE` or `FALSE * FALSE` or `TRUE * FALSE` = `0`. Then `SUMPRODUCT` sums all `1` and get so the count of where both are true.

Comment: Thank you Axel. I did understood the formula and that is exactly what I want. Just one question: is it possible to, instead of having "=F7", having text, like "local1". I tried but it gives an error, just wondering if is possible to do it any other way, because like this, I have to have a control column with all the locations ....

Comment: Yes, it is :) Just have the ="local1"

Comment: Of course the Formula in `G7` could also be `=SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A$20="local1")*($B$1:$D$20<>""))`. What error you get?